# Inequality about multicolor Ramsey Number

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I am self studying studying an applied combinatorics course and trying to prove that:

$$R(\underbrace{3, 3, \cdots, 3}_{n}) = R_n(3) \leq 1 + n!(1 + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + \cdots + \frac{1}{n!})$$

I tried using induction and there is equality for $n=2$, i.e. $R(3,3) = 6$, but I'm stuck with the inductive step. I'm also having a little trouble in conceptually understanding what Ramsey Numbers mean, and maybe that's why I'm stuck. Would really really appreciate any help. Thank you!

**Edited:** I was able to solve it following @kabenyuk's suggestion on using the reasoning from this post: [Upper bound on multicolor ramsey number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015658/upper-bound-on-multicolor-ramsey-number?rq=1)

Comment: It seems that a little refinement of the reasoning [from here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2015658/upper-bound-on-multicolor-ramsey-number?rq=1) allows you to prove your inequality. Try it.

Comment: @kabenyuk Thank you! I was able to use induction and manipulate the inequality from Alex Ravsky's answer to show the bound! Huge thanks!